# binomial distribution density asymptote

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, density-estimation

mathematically, why does this function have an asymptote around 0.63?  is there an way to formally describe this asymptote?

here's the pattern:

- *two coin flips, what's the probability that at least one of the flips turns up heads? - 75%*
- *roll a three-sided die three times.  what's the probability that at least one roll will be a 1? - 70.37%*
- *roll a four-sided die four times.  what's the probability that at least one roll will be a 1? - 68.36%*
- *roll a five-sided die five times.  what's the probability that at least one roll will be a 1? - 67.23%*
- **roll an X-sided die X times.  what's the probability that at least one roll will be a 1?**

i'd like to understand why as X gets larger, these percentages move toward ~0.63

here's the R code to plot out what i'm envisioning:

```
myfun <- Vectorize( function( w ) sum( dbinom( seq( w ) , w , 1/w ) ) )
x <- 1:10000
y <- myfun(x)
plot(x,y)
```

the Y axis of this plot never dips below 0.63

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Hint: $0.63$ approximates$1-1/e,$ obtained as the limiting value of $1-(1-1/n)^n.$

Comment: right.  because `myfun2 <- function( w ) ( 1 - ( 1 - 1 / w )^w )` is equivalent to my function above.  thanks so much!